# Вывод курса валют с API JSON ПриватБанка на сайт

Tags: wordpress, json, api

все работает, вставил функцию, но выводит 7 символов с apijson привата например 28.65000.  и так во всех валютах Подскажите пожалуйста  что можно прописать чтоб последние три символа не выводились на сайт.
Код примера:

```
    function _isCurl(){
  return function_exists('curl_version');
}
function exchange_rates() {
    if (_iscurl()){
            $url = "https://api.privatbank.ua/p24api/pubinfo?exchange&json&coursid=11";
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            $output = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            if(!$output) return false;
            $courses = json_decode($output,true);
    } else{
            echo "CURL is disabled";
    }
    $currs = ['USD','EUR'];
    $res = '';
    foreach($courses as $course){
            if(in_array($course['ccy'], $currs)){
                    $res .= "{$course['ccy']}: {$course['buy']} ";
            }
    }
    return $res;
}
add_shortcode( 'exchange_rates', 'exchange_rates' );
```

Comment: Прописать нужно в гугл запрос "php форматирование чисел"

Answer (score 1):

Для форматирования используйте PHP функцию [number_format](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.number-format.php) или функцию WordPress [number_format_i18n()](https://wp-kama.ru/function/number_format_i18n). В вашем случае в цикле следует обернуть конкатенацию переменной $res. Пример:

```php
    $res .= $course['ccy'] . ": " . number_format_i18n( $course['buy'], 2 );
```

Comment: заменил код работает, символы отображаются верно. только заменился вместо букв EUR и USD - символ " : "  перед курсом доллара и евро...

Comment: Поправил, можете попробовать изменённый код

Comment: Годнота. Спасибо огромное ! Все заработало на УРА! Названия есть, символы красивые, просто сказка...лайк

Answer (score 0):

Есть готовое решение для PHP. Бесплатный API для получения курсов валют в банках и обменниках Украины из сайта https://kurstoday.com.ua

https://github.com/pavlovich-app/KursToday-API